# Use of 주시다 and 드리다

Tags: word-usage

So far I have encountered examples of using 주시다 and 드리다. And I know sometimes 주시다 used instead of 드리다 and vice versa.

Like:

전해 주시겠습니까?

전해 드리겠습니까? -> wrong

알려 주셔서 감사드립니다

알려 주셔서 감사주십니다 -> wrong

But I am still confused on the usage of these two. Could anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two distinct differences between 주시다 and 드리다:

- (해)드리다 is used instead of (해)주다 when the person for whom the favour is done needs to be shown politeness in that particular speech situation.
- (으)시 just means you are being polite about the person doing the action. You could add it to 주다 (to become 주시다) OR to 드리다 (to become 드리시다).

When you are using 전해드리다 or 전해주다, the person the favour is being done for is the person the relevant information is being told to.

전해 주시겠습니까? could mean 'Would you convey that to me (or to someone else of a lower status)?'. You could be talking to someone higher or even, in a formal situation, to someone slightly lower.

전해 드리겠습니까? is also fine - it would mean 'Will you convey that (to a higher person)?'

알려 주셔서 감사드립니다 Is a way to thank someone senior for letting you (or someone else of a low status) know something.

알려 주셔서 감사주십니다 - the most straightforward reason that this is strange is that Koreans just don't use 주다 with 감사. If someone is thanking someone slightly lower directly, they would just say 감사합니다. If you were reporting the fact, you'd use 감사 해 하다. <sub>Also, a humble form is being used for the person receiving the information '**주**셔서', the person who did the favour is somewhat respected '주**셔**서', and a somewhat respected person is doing the thanking (감사주**십**니다) - and this cannot be the person doing the talking, which logically seems like a convoluted situation!</sub>

Comment: Let me summarize your meaning: 주시다 used when giving respect to the one whom I speak to, but not the one favour is to be shown; 드리다 used when giving respect to both audience?

Comment: *주시다 used when giving respect to the one whom I speak to, but not the one favour is to be shown* - correct, if you assume that the person doing the favour is the same person you are talking to.

Comment: *드리다 used when giving respect to both audience?* - it gives respect to the person receiving the favour, but *not* to the person doing the action. If you are asking your boss to tell something to his boss (showing *both* respect), you could use 드리시다.

Comment: Or put it even simpler, 드리다 is the 'version' of 주다 where the person receiving the favor is superior to the person doing the favor, and add 시 before 다 if the person doing the favor (which is the subject), is also to be respected/honored. Correct?

Comment: @busukxuan the choice of 주다/드리다 isn't specifically about the *favour giver→favour receiver* relationship - it's about whether the favour receiver should be honoured. That could be quite complicated - it could depend on the relationship between the favour receiver and the person you're speaking to, for example.

Comment: @busukxuan http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/303/how-do-i-know-when-i-should-honor-someone

Comment: @topomorto sry I was being imprecise with my wording, I did mean the "whether should be honored", aside that was what I said correct?

Comment: @busukxuan I think we can summarise it as 'use 드리다 when the receiver of the favour should be honoured; use 시 when the giver of the favour should be honoured'. Hopefully that agrees with my bullet points!

Comment: So none of these are showing respect to the one whom speaker is speaking to, right? (Given that the listener is not the favour receiver or favour giver)

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy - by 'these', do you mean your example sentences?

Comment: I mean in general, no matter 주시다, 드리다 or 드리시다, none of them are giving respect to the listener, right? After all it has just been a short time I learned Korean.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy as I understand it, that's correct - unless the listener *also* happens to be the person giving or receiving the favour (though that often will be the case).

Comment: Which means giving a command as a superior would use 드리다.

Comment: @busukxuan I don't quite understand what you mean - can you give an example?

Comment: @topomorto for example a captain gives command to his soldiers

Comment: @busukxuan I can't see how 드리다 could relevant in that situation anyway, as no favour is being done, but I may be wrong. Can you give an example sentence in Korean?

Comment: @topomorto *내일 아침 여기에 모여 드리다*, is it correct? And would using 모여***라*** eliminate the need of 드리다?

Comment: Very interesting post, I think I finally understand why I have to say "아버님께 생신 축하드린다고 전해 드려" instead of "전해 줘" - the person that the congratulation is to be conveyed to determines the verb, but my relation to the listener determines it's form!

Comment: @busukxuan if you're asking someone to do something for you, then you'd never use '드리다', because you don't use honorifics for yourself. My local native Korean also says that 모여 드리다 would sound so excessively polite so as to be sarcastic.