# About adding -주 to the verb stem

Tags: verb, north-korean

As I know, the ending -시 is added to the verb stem to show a courtesy to somebody. But also I faced some cases with

1) -주 endings instead of -시 (미래도 희망도 다 맡**아주**는),

2) -주시 endings (for example 찾아주시면서/찾으시면서 and 말씀하시였다/말씀해주시였다),

without change of the verb meaning (im my opinion).

Anyway, does the -주 ending change the meaning of the verb, or it just adds formality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **아/어/여 주다** Pattern means that you are doing something *for the benefit* of someone. Think of cases where you would say ".... for me" or " for someone" in English.

> 말씀하시였다 - you said/told something.
>
> 말씀하시였다 - you said/told something *for someone's benefit*. (Perhaps you told them some useful information that they are grateful for.).

Note that if the person for whom the favour is being done requires would be higher in status than the person *saying the sentence*, you wouldn't use 주다, but instead, 드리다.  [Use of 주시다 and 드리다](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/298/use-of-%EC%A3%BC%EC%8B%9C%EB%8B%A4-and-%EB%93%9C%EB%A6%AC%EB%8B%A4/300) has some more explanation.

The difference between -주다 and 주시다 corresponds with the normal meaning of the (으)시 particle - it confers respect onto the actor of the verb (the person *doing* the favour. Again hopefully the linked question is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**동사 + 보조동사 (verb + helping verb) :** For instance, 봐 주다
(봐=see, 주다=give, meaning=give an irregular benefit), 도와 주다
(help=give a help)

**보조 동사의 효과 (effect) :** 맡다 = undertake

Handle the enemy of east (order => intimate expression => honorific
expression) :

(동쪽의 적은 니가) 맡어, 맡아라, 맡을래? => 말아 줄래 ? => 맡으세요.
맡아 주세요.

He handled the enemy of east

(동쪽의 적은 그가) 맡았다 => 맡아 주었다 => 맡으셨습니다, 맡아
주시었다, 맡아 주셨다.

**보조 동사의 효과 II :** Different from 맡다, we have 갖다 주다 (take
and give). In this case, we can not abbreviate a helping verb 주다.

He took a milk 그는 우유를 가졌다.

He took a milk and gave it to me 그는 우유를 갖다 주었다.

The second sentence contains more explanation.

**보조 동사의 종류 :** 주다 (service), 싶다 (wanting : 학교에 가고 싶다 I want to go to school), and so on.